# How to create an ObservableCollection using LINQ in Silverlight

Tags: linq, silverlight

In a non-Silverlight world, it is easy to use LINQ to create an ObservableCollection.  This is because the ObservableCollection class has constructors that accept any IEnumerable<T> or List<T>.  However, the Silverlight version does not!  This means that code such as:

```
var list = (from item in e.Result
            select new ViewModel(item)).ToList();

Items = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ViewModel>(list);
```

will not work in Silverlight.

Is there another option to make this work besides resorting to a for-each statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well That works if you are using Silverlight 4.
try this:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll)
        {
            var c = new ObservableCollection<T>();
            foreach (var e in coll)
                c.Add(e);
            return c;
        }
    }
```

found in: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/39487/262505.aspx

Comment: I didn't know this deficiency has already been addressed in SL4, thanks!

Comment: @sonofpirate:  In fact in SL4 you can drop the ToList since there is an constructor on `ObservableCollection<T>` that takes `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Excellent!  I can't wait until we get the green light to upgrade to SL4!

Answer (score 5):

I dont think so, but you can make it cleaner using this extension method.

```
 public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll) {
        var c = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        foreach (var e in coll)
            c.Add(e);
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Barring another option, this was the approach I was going to use.  I was just hoping there was another, more graceful way to get it done.

Comment: @sonofpirate:  In SL3 this is very good way, even in SL4 I might be inclined to create this extension method anyway (although using the correct constructor in the implementation).