# Cant insert a object into a silverlight databound combo box

Tags: c#, silverlight

Until recently I had a combo box that was bound to a Linq queried IEnumerable of a DataService.Obj type in the bind method, and all worked fine

```
private IEnumerable<DataService.Obj> _GeneralList;
private IEnumerable<DataService.Obj> _QueriedList;


private void Bind()
{
    _GeneralList = SharedLists.GeneralList;
    _QueriedList = _GeneralList.Where(q =>q.ID >1000);

    cmbobox.ItemsSource = _QueriedList;
}
```

Then I had to change the method to insert a new obj and set that object as the default obj and now I get a "***System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object***" exception. I know this has to do with inserting into a linq queried ienumerable but I cant fix it. Any help will be gratefully received.

```
private IEnumerable<DataService.Obj> _GeneralList;
private IEnumerable<DataService.Obj> _QueriedList;

private void Bind()
{
    _GeneralList = SharedLists.GeneralList;
    _QueriedList = _GeneralList.Where(q =>q.ID >1000);

    cmbobox.ItemsSource = _QueriedList;

    DataService.Obj info = new DataService.Obj();
    info.ID = "0";
    (cmbobox.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DataService.Obj>).Insert(0,info);
    cmbobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression :-

```
(cmbobox.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DataService.Obj>)
```

Will return null.  The `ItemsSource` is what ever was assigned to it. In this case a LINQ supplied object that implements `IEnumerable<DataService.Obj>` hence the `as` returns null (LINQ knows nothing of `ObservableCollection<T>` and certainly doesn't use it).

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692241/how-to-create-an-observablecollection-using-linq-in-silverlight) to create a `ToObservableCollection` extension method.

That said I'm gonna guess that your actual objective is to have "`<N/A>`" element at the top of the list right? If so try this:-

```
 cmbobox.ItemsSource=  Enumerable.Repeat(new DataService.Obj() {ID = 0}, 1)
                     .Union(_QueriedList));
```

This inserts as single `DataService.Obj` instance with an ID of 0 as the first item of an `IEnumerable<DataService.Obj` followed by all the items in  _QueriedList.  No need to attempt to insert a value into collection with this approach.

Comment: I ended up creating an extension method as the .Union method did not work for me. And you were quite right as to why my method was failing and the general purpose of the method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting your new item before binding to the control.

```
private IEnumerable<DataService.Obj> _GeneralList; 
private IEnumerable<DataService.Obj> _QueriedList; 

private void Bind() 
{ 
    _GeneralList = SharedLists.GeneralList; 
    _QueriedList = _GeneralList.Where(q =>q.ID >1000).ToList(); 

    DataService.Obj info = new DataService.Obj(); 
    info.ID = "0"; 
    _QueriedList.Insert(0,info); 

    cmbobox.ItemsSource = _QueriedList; 

    cmbobox.SelectedIndex = 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think _GeneralList.Where is going to return an ObservableCollection

So when you cast using as on the line:
(cmbobox.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection).Insert(0,info);

you're always going to get a null reference.  instead you might do this:

```
_GeneralList = SharedLists.GeneralList;
_QueriedList = _GeneralList.Where(q =>q.ID >1000);

// ***this line changed***
cmbobox.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<DataService.Obj>(_QueriedList);

DataService.Obj info = new DataService.Obj();
info.ID = "0";
(cmbobox.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DataService.Obj>).Insert(0,info);
cmbobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```